# How to change the list of "characters treated as letters" on an RDS MYSQL DB?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, amazon-rds

MYSQL has a set of characters that it considers to be "letters", meaning "part of a word, rather than a special character", which is (I think) basically all letters and numbers (digits).

I have an Amazon RDS-hosted MYSQL DB, and in that DB I want to change it so that `.` (full stop) is treated as a "letter", ie a normal part of a word.

The MYSQL docs list a couple of ways to go about it, on here:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html
(see the "Character Set Modifications" section).

The first involves a change to the source code and a recompile - obviously that's not an option with RDS.  The second option involves modifying a character set xml file, and the third involves adding a new collation file.

Are any of these options possible with RDS, and if so, how?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add a collation, you'd have to edit XML files in the MySQL server's charset directory. Instructions are here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation-simple-8bit.html

I doubt you can do this on RDS, since you don't have access to ssh into the host where MySQL is running.

This is the tradeoff with RDS. You get a standard MySQL instance, not customizable. But you get a lot of tedious database administration tasks taken off your shoulders.

If you want full control to customize MySQL, you can certainly run it yourself by installing a MySQL package on an EC2 instance (in fact, you can probably save a fair amount on your AWS bill this way). But you take responsibility for a lot of work to administer the server too.

Comment: Thanks.  We can't (will not) move off RDS now - we used to manage our own server, but we enjoy the benefits of AWS too much.